# Launcheffect theme does not work on an openshift for wordpress installlation

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, openshift

I have installed the [launcheffect](http://launcheffectapp.com/) theme on my openshift wordpress 3.6.1:

[My Page](http://landingpage-sysalgo.rhcloud.com/)

This is what I get.

[image]

My problem is, I have installed the theme as explained on the launcheffect page, however I do not get a functional page. 
I really would appreciate your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its stuck at LaunchEffect's startup page. I would suggest taking a look at http://wakeupempowered.com/?p=7 as it seems to have a good walk through.

I think the trick is you have to configure your wordpress blog a bit more and then start install the launcheffect theme. Otherwise it will apply that signup page to everything.